# How Can I Show Count Of 2 Column Values Into A Pivot Table With Grouped Values As Rows?

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, powerpivot

I have a data table in Excel simplified as below.

[image: Raw Data]

I am trying to make a Pivot Table as below, with Week Data expected to grow each week.

[image: Pivot Data]

Current Pivot Table uses Data Models, so I believe I am limited to Measures and no Calculated Fields (correct me if I am wrong).

I have tried creating 2 Data Models and create a relationship based on Week, but it is not allowed since the values are not unique. Getting the Items Sold count might be the missing piece I need. I think Inventory column should be solved by creating a measure to find the difference between Items Added and Items Sold.

I have been pulling my hair out trying to solve this. I feel it should be possible, and I am just missing the obvious solution in front of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

1. Your source table is named *Data*
2. You have another table named *Weeks* which comprises a single column named *Week* and which contains a distinct list of all weeks to be found in the *Data* table, e.g. "WEEK01", "WEEK02", "WEEK03", "WEEK04", "WEEK05"

First create two relationships between the *Data* and *Weeks* tables, one to the *Added Week* column (which should be **active**), and one to the *Sold Week* column (which should be **inactive**).

Then create the following **measures**:

```
Items Added:=COUNTROWS( Data )

Items Sold:=0
    + CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS( Data ),
        USERELATIONSHIP ( Data[Sold Week], Weeks[Week] )
    )

Inventory:=VAR ThisWeek =
    MIN( Weeks[Week] )
VAR CumulativeAdded =
    CALCULATE( [Items Added], Weeks[Week] <= ThisWeek )
VAR CumulativeSold =
    CALCULATE(
        [Items Sold],
        FILTER(
            ALL( Weeks ),
            Weeks[Week] <= ThisWeek
                && NOT ( ISBLANK( Weeks[Week] ) )
        )
    )
RETURN
    CumulativeAdded - CumulativeSold
```

which can then be placed in a Pivot Table alongside the *Week* column from the *Weeks* table.

A (blank) row may be present in this table, which you can filter out if you wish.

Comment: Perfect. I was also able to solve remaining parts of the report based of the idea you provided. Thanks!